# linux + how to use the tput bold in echo command

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, echo, tput

we have the follwing array - list1 and list2

```
list1="node23 node76 node 34"
list2="node02 node2 node9 node21"
```

we want to bold the list2 so list1 will printed without bold and list2 with bold

example

```
echo ${list1[*]}  ${list2[*]}
```

node23 node76 node 34 **node02 node2 node9 node21**

so how to insert tput bold in echo so list2 will be bold?

1. tput bold - will **bold** the words
2. tput sgr0 will return the bold to normal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC:

```
echo ${list1[*]}  "$(tput bold)" ${list2[*]} "$(tput sgr0)"
```

Comment: Can I somehow only turn off boldness with tput, preserving coloring? I know that sequence 21 exists specifically for that, but I cannot find it in `tput` :/

Comment: sorry but I don't understand, are you referring to some ANSI escape code?

Comment: yes, this sequence is bold off, and I wonder if tput can do it too: `\033[21m`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know an answer for this question, the escape code doesn't work for me in xterm or Linux console and some answers and Wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code say that it's _Doubly underlined_. Maybe ask a new question and someone will answer.